# calling a function as an action of another function

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get one function to run as an action of another function but it's running too early. I'm trying to get the `nameRequest()` function to be called after the text fades out but the strange thing is I can see the text in the corner of my screen before the text fades out and then when it fades it just moves to the proper CG point. I'm very confused by this. I would appreciate it if anybody could offer some insight. Thank you.

```
func fadeViewInThenOut(view : UILabel, delay: TimeInterval) {

                let animationDuration = 1.00

                // Fade in the view
                UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    view.alpha = 1
                    }) { (Bool) -> Void in

                        // After the animation completes, fade out the view after a delay

                        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: delay, animations: { () -> Void in
                            view.alpha = 0
                            nameRequest()
                        }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            fadeViewInThenOut(view: newwelcomeLabel, delay: 5)
        }
        newWelcomeLabel()

        func nameRequest() {
            let namerequestLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 50))
            namerequestLabel.text = "what's your name?"
            namerequestLabel.textAlignment = .center
            namerequestLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x/1.3, y: self.view.center.y/2)
            namerequestLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
            self.view.addSubview(namerequestLabel)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine the order of in which code will execute in an animation block. You are seeing the label appear right away because `nameRequest` and `addSubview` are not animatable. These methods will execute immediately and your animatable properties, such as `view.alpha` and `namerequestLabel.center`, will behave according to the parameters you supply to `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` If you really want `nameRequest` to run after your animations you should implement the `completion` handler and call `nameRequest` from there.